# i am trying to send a signed transaction for my solidity code but i am encounting some error can anyone suggest me the fix?

Tags: solidity, web3js, myetherwallet

```
pragma solidity^0.5.0;
import "./TokenSale.sol";
contract Dice{

    TokenSale public tokenSale;
    address tokensaleaddress;

    struct player_details{
        address pAddress;
        string pName;
         }

    struct gameRecords{
        address playerAddress;
        uint selected_num;
        uint rolled_num;
        bool result;
        uint ptoken;
        uint timestamp;
    }

    constructor (TokenSale _tokenSale) public {
      tokenSale = _tokenSale;
    }


    mapping(uint =>gameRecords) public outcome;
    mapping(uint => player_details) public details;

    uint public playerid=0;
    uint played=1;
    uint playercount=0;

      function setplayerDetails(string memory _pName) public{
        details[playerid] = player_details(msg.sender,_pName);
        playerid++;
        playercount++;
      }

    function addGameEvent(uint _betplaced, uint _rollresult,bool _result,uint _ptoken) public{
        require(playercount >=1 );
        outcome[played] = gameRecords(msg.sender,_betplaced,_rollresult,_result,_ptoken,now);
        played++;
    }

    function tokenfetch() public {
        // require (playercount >=1);
        tokenSale.buyTokens(100);
    }

  }
```

Here is my App.js raw transaction code

```js
  const Web3 = require('web3');
  const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/f072e47f51ae4419beecd1c3c16d0124"));
  const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");
  let account = this.owner_account;
  let nonce;
  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account).then(_nonce => {
    nonce = _nonce.toString(16)
  });
  let myPrivateKey = this.owner_private_key;
  let privateKey = new ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer(myPrivateKey, 'hex');
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS, {
  from: account,
  });
  let gasPrice = window.web3_.toHex(500000000000) // 500 Gwei
  let gasLimitHex = window.web3_.toHex(6000000)
  const functionAbi = contract.methods.myFunctionName(myArgument).encodeABI()
  let rawTx = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'gasPrice': gasPrice,
    'gasLimit': gasLimitHex,
    'from': account,
    'to': this.to_contract_address,
    'data': data,
    'chainId': '0x03'
  }

  let tx = new Tx(rawTx);
  tx.sign(privateKey);
  tx.serialize();
  console.log(tx.validate());
  let serializedTx = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
  console.log(serializedTx);
```

Comment: "some error" <-- Is the error a secret for some reason?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'ethereumjs-tx' although i have ethereumjs-tx installed i already checked that.

Comment: So you can reduce the code in your question down to just `App.js` with just `require("ethereumjs-tx");` in it. Do you get the same error then? If so, please share how you installed the library and how you're executing your `App.js`.

Comment: (And please delete all the irrelevant code, like the Solidity contract and all the JavaScript other than the `require`.)